# TextView не очищается!

Tags: android, textview

Для очистки TextView использую

```
textView_vivod.setText("");
```

Также пробывал

```
textView_vivod.setText(null);
```

Не очищается тестовое поле перед вставкой текста.

```
String text = String.valueOf(editText_text.getText());//получаем текст
            int key = Integer.parseInt(editText_num.getText().toString());//получаем число

            for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)

// Построение зашифрованной строки сообщения,
                encmsg = encmsg + (char) (text.charAt(i) ^ key);

            //очищаем текстовое поле
            textView_vivod.setText("");
            //textView_vivod.setText(null);

            //вставляем зашифрованный текст
            textView_vivod.setText(encmsg);
```

Полный код

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText_text;
    EditText editText_num;
    TextView textView_vivod;
    Button button;

    String encmsg = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText_num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_vvod_kod);
        editText_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_vvod_text);
        textView_vivod = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_zahifrovanoe);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_zashifrovat);

    }

    public void Zashifrovat(View view) {

        if (editText_text.getText().toString().equals("")) {
// Здесь код, если editText_text пуст
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Введите фразу!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
// Здесь код, если editText_num пуст
        } else if (editText_num.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Введите число-пороль!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
        else {

            String text = String.valueOf(editText_text.getText());//получаем текст
            int key = Integer.parseInt(editText_num.getText().toString());//получаем число

            for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)

// Построение зашифрованной строки сообщения,
                encmsg = encmsg + (char) (text.charAt(i) ^ key);

            //очищаем текстовое поле
            textView_vivod.setText("");
            //textView_vivod.setText(null);

            //вставляем зашифрованный текст
            textView_vivod.setText(encmsg);

        }
    }
}
```

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: что не работает? вы сетите вначале пустую строку, и сразу encmsg. какой результат вы хотели увидеть?

Comment: а как вы определили что строка не очищается?=))))

Comment: обожаю такие имена, как методов Zashifrovat, ссылки в виде R.id.editText_vvod_kod, я всегда буду уверен в своей востребованности на рынке :D....... По сути вопроса, перед for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) напишите простую строчку encmsg = "";

Answer (score 5):

Все у вас чистится, чистить нужно переменную encmsg.

```
encmsg = "";
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
   encmsg = encmsg + (char) (text.charAt(i) ^ key);
}
textView_vivod.setText(encmsg);
```

Вот с таким кодом у Вас все взлетит

Answer (score -1):

Блин, как все просто оказалось))
Спасибо большое!!!)))
Особое спасибо Chaynik 
Пример кстати взят из Шильдта "Руководство для начинающих"...Видать не внимательно читал))
Имена методов и прочее конечно смешные, но я учусь))
Если серьезно, спасибо, что находите время ответить на глупые вопросы...
Дай Бог Вам счастья и здоровья))))